# printing two dimension matrix in java

Tags: java, arrays, printing

I'm trying to print a two dimensional double array in java with a unique form that all doubles should be in #.#### format so I used DecimalFormat method but still have some problem in printing 0 or doubles that contain 0, also note all doubles that I want to print is between 0 and 1.

[image]

Comment: Please add your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have always the same size occupied by a number, you can use the following pattern

```
0.00000
```

instead of

```
#.#####
```

Here are how the numbers appears for both solutions:

```
0.00000          #.#####
-------          --------    
0.00000          0
1.00000          1
0.34543          0.34543
0.50000          0.5
```

The difference between 0 and # is the following:

> 0 Number  Yes Digit
>
> #    Number  Yes Digit, **zero shows as absent**

You can check the full documentation in the javadoc of [`DecimalFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) in the section *Special Pattern Characters*

Printing the numbers with the pattern `0.00000` will generate a well aligned matrix.

```
0.00000 1.00000 0.63467
0.34000 0.34245 0.00000
0.34255 0.98455 1.00000
```

with the pattern `#.####` they will appear not aligned as follow

```
0 1 0.63467
0.34 0.34245 0
0.34255 0.98455 1
```